# List<class> add string

Tags: c#, string, list

This is the class:

```
public class Vokabel
{
    string DV;
    string eV;      

    public string _DV 
    {
        get { return DV;}
        set { DV = value;} 
    }       
    public string EV 
    {
        get{return eV;}
        set{eV = value;}
    }

    public Vokabel (string dv, string ev)
    {
        this._DV = dv;
        this.EV = ev; 
    }


}
```

And i want to add Userchoice to Vokabel1.

```
List<Vokabel> Vokabel1 = new List<Vokabel> (); 
        for (int i = 0; i< 9; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Vokabel["+i+"]:" );
            string Userchoice = Console.ReadLine();
            Vokabel1.Add(Userchoice); 
        }
```

This won't run. I tried to split `Userchoice` - don't work. 
Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: You have to create an object of type `Vokabel`, you can't just add a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct it doesn't work, I guess it even doesn't compile.

You have to supply two values to the constructor of `Vokabel1` and you have to use the constructor.

```
string[] values = Userchoice.Split(':');

Vokabel1.Add(new Vokabel(values[0], values[1]));
```

Comment: @user3092365: I updated the example to split on ':' so the user has to enter one line.

Comment: @user3092365: Of course you can replace the `:` with space, or anything else.

Comment: Yes - this is how it should work.Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You try to add `string Userchoice` as a `Vokabel`. That makes no sense. A string is structurally different from a `Vokabel`.

Think about what you *want* to happen. It is not clear from the question what you want. There's no obvious conversion from a string to a `Vokabel`.

In any case you can only add `Vokabel` instances to the list. Somehow create such an instance from the string that the user entered.

Comment: "You try to add string Userchoice as a Vokabel. That makes no sense." - I know . But I thought it would be easier four you to understand my problem. " It is not clear from the question what you want." - Sorry , I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to prompt for each of the properties, and use these for the constructor on your `Vokabel` class. Something like:

```
   for (int i = 0; i< 9; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a _DV for Vokabel["+i+"]:" );
        string dv = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a EV for Vokabel["+i+"]:" );
        string ev = Console.ReadLine();
        Vokabel1.Add(new Vokabel(dv, ev)); 
    }
```

Comment: This works. But I would prefer, that the User only needs to enter one line.

Comment: @user3092365: I would say this can be up voted (and I did) because it's an approach. I provided an approach with a single string. But you can't really fault Stuart for this approach because you're question never **clearly** defined what you wanted.

Comment: In one line, you would need to `parse` or `deserialize` what the user typed in, which would also imply that the user knows what the encoding scheme is (e.g. comma separated, or @MichaelPerrenoud demonstrates a colon separated encoding). But obviously validation and error handling will be required in such an instance.

Comment: @ Michael I can't upvote because of my reputation. Stuarts answer is short and good.

Answer (score 1):

So one clever approach would be to use an `implicit` cast:

```
public class Vokabel
{
    string DV;
    string eV;

    public string _DV
    {
        get { return DV; }
        set { DV = value; }
    }
    public string EV
    {
        get { return eV; }
        set { eV = value; }
    }

    public Vokabel(string dv, string ev)
    {
        this._DV = dv;
        this.EV = ev;
    }

    public static implicit operator Vokabel(string vals)
    {
        var valsArray = vals.Split(':');
        return new Vokabel(valsArray[0], valsArray[1]);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Vokabel> Vokabel1 = new List<Vokabel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Vokabel[" + i + "]:");
            string Userchoice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Userchoice))
            {
                break;
            }
            Vokabel1.Add(Userchoice);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, if you use the input:

```
A:B
C:D
E:F
...
```

it will split on the `:` for each value and create a new `Vokabel` from the users input. Armed with that, you can easily see how flexible this could be.

**NOTE:** this is a bit of *indirection* because it's not naturally evident how a `string` casts to a `Vokabel`, but it's an approach.

Bear in mind that the reason your code didn't work is because you weren't building a `List<string>` and so just adding a `string` without building some kind of code to translate that into a `Vokabel` clearly fails.

Comment: "clever" => not a good thing.

Comment: @usr: not that I don't understand what you're implying, but it's probably a pretty subjective comment.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because you are attempting to add a string where it expects an object

Think of it like this

You approach a door. The door is locked. The only way to open the door is with a cake covered in chocolate and filled with pudding.

By just doing List.Add(YourString) you are trying to force pudding into the lock without the rest of the cake.

What you need to do is this

```
List<Vokabel> Vokabel1 = new List<Vokabel> (); 
        for (int i = 0; i< 9; i++) {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Vokabel["+i+"]:" );

            //This is pudding
            string Userchoice = Console.ReadLine();

            //This is your cake
            Vokabel temp = new Vokabel(){ EV = Userchoice }; //I used EV for your userchoice


            Vokabel1.Add(temp); 
        }
```

This creates a new object, fills it with pudding and puts it in your list. Get it?